# open website if "password" is exactly what is needed (github pages)

Tags: javascript, html, github

Sorry if this is a relatively basic question but I'm getting a little bit frustrated, and this is the first time I'm using GitHub Pages

What I want is:

- Accept text in form
- Compare text in form with password "pass"

  - if correct, go to a different html site
  - else, do nothing

thanks in advance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <form onSubmit="checkPass(this)">
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input type="text" name="Password" id="pwd" size="20"> 
      <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
    
    <script>
    function checkPass(passForm) {
      var password = document.getElementById('pwd');
      if (password == "pass"){
        windows.open("Website extension here")
      }
        
    }
    </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But anyone can view source and open the website right?

Comment: Please don't use this code on a live website - unless you are well aware that it provides no protection what so ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But anyone can view source and open the website right? Everything is right except you missed `.value`. Add a `return false` and make `windows` as `window`:

```js
function checkPass() {
  var password = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
  if (password == "pass") {
    window.open("https://example.com")
  }
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="checkPass(); return false;">
  <label>Password:</label>
  <input type="text" name="Password" id="pwd" size="20">
  <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

The above code will not work in sandbox. So try it using [CodeSandbox Demo](https://mzoqf.csb.app/).

Comment: Thanks! I know this is open source, but I'm not going to use it for anything important. This was more like a test for using a website in GitHub.

Comment: @aeter All the best! Thanks for taking the advice.